# How to make one element disappear after you made another one appear using javascript. triggered by scrolling?

Tags: javascript

I have text inside an element that will appear in the header when you scroll down.

But then I also want to make the first section of the page disappear at the same time. So i set the javascript at the same scroll point. This is a small feature, I don't want to rely on any library. So just plain javascript solution suggestions please.

### HTML

```
<header class="header-home">
  <div>
    Company
  </div>
  <span class="header-copy">
    is so awesome
  </span>

  <button></button>  
</header>

<!-- test content -->
<section class="landing-bg">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</section>
```

### Javascript

I started with the top block of code and all worked fine to make the text in the `header-copy` to appear when you scroll 300px.

```
var span = document.querySelectorAll('.header-home .header-copy')[0];

span.style.display = "none";

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 300) {
    span.style.display = "inline-block";
  }
  else {
    span.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

But then I wanted to make the first section in my page go away.

```
/* makes the top content go away */

var content = document.getElementsByClassName("landing-bg")[0];

content.style.display = "block";

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 300) {
    content.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

A full demo is available on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/MKWEjz)

Comment: What happens if you combine the two "addEventListener"s?  Since you listening for the same thing, why have 2?

Comment: @ovaherenow i added `content.style.display = "none";` under `span.style.display = "inline-block";` and removed the second code block but for the same result.

Comment: If I remove the first code block i still get the twitching. so the problem seens to be just the second block to make the section disappear, then i got to refactor to nest in a much cleaner way.

Comment: For some reason, when I use your CodePen, and I insert valid images, the "is awesome" does flicker, but it automatically scrolls me back up to the top.

Comment: @ovaherenow i think i just had a typo somewhere. Considered deleting, but will answer it with my new code because someone might want this for implementing something similar.

Comment: Yeah, and you might want to clean up the text you put in the CodePen too.  Just realized that it's very NSFW.

Comment: @ovaherenow oh good point. I switched Samuel Ipsum to Bacon Ipsum.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up nesting the code and verifying class names. Answering this rather than deleting just in case someone can use this code as an example.

### Javascript

```
/* Allows you to select a class within a class */
var span = document.querySelectorAll('.header-home .header-copy')[0];
span.style.display = "none";

/* you can select an element with a specific class*/
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("landing-bg")[0];
content.style.display = "block";

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  /* edit to the scroll point that you need */
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 300) {
    span.style.display = "inline-block";
    content.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    content.style.display = "block";
    span.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```